# Если приложение свернуть то начинает лагать Mac из-за Semaphore.WaitForSignal

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Проблема такая, если открыть приложение и пользоваться им то всё ок. съедает примерно 20% ЦП.
Но стоит только свернуть игру, открыть мессенджер, например, то начинаются дикие лаги.
При фокусе на приложении, лаги прекращаются.
Попробовал в редакторе запустить и потерять фокус, получается тоже самое, так и узнал что это из-за семафора

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]